# different ng-models in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing a problem in AngularJS! (I am very new to AngularJS)

I am trying to setup n `select fields` with x `options` and I want to have different `ng-model` on the `select fields`.

At the same time I want to disable the option that has been selected in the first select field in all other `select fields`.

I have tried serveral different things. And the problem was that I could not handle the different models in the ng-repeat

Here is my JSON-File to make things a little bit clearer:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  text: "Question1",
  selected:false
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: "Question2",
  selected:false
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: "Question3",
  selected:false
}, {
  id: 4,
  text: "Question4",
  selected:false
}, {
  id: 5,
  text: "Question5",
  selected:false
}];
```

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ol9b5ZzNVNS4KML1DwK?p=preview) is one of my attempts. The problem is that the more select fields I have the messier it gets.

I have also found [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/5weXSo9pmovjJDURcpY4?p=preview), but I can't get it to work for my questions in example.

Basically, what I would need to have is something like this:

```
<select ng-change="onChange()" ng-options='q.value for q in questions | filter:{selected:  false}' ng-model='option[$index]'><option value="">-- pick one --</option>  </select>
```

But for some reason the $index is not interpreted as the current index, but as plain string.

Comment: I am not able to understand what are you trying to do

Comment: are you wanting to create a drop down?

Comment: Did you have a look at my fiddles?
I just want to have a number of select fields with different models, but all have the same basic options, but if there is one option selected I want it to be disabled in all the other select fields

Comment: I looked at ur fiddle

Comment: there are two of them.

Comment: Are you wanting each question to be disabled after they have been selected?

Comment: yes "At the same time I want to disable the option that has been selected in the first select field in all other select fields."

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of question sets. Using ng-repeat you can create multiple drop downs with the same set of initial options.

```
<div ng-repeat="set in questionSets track by set.id">
      <select ng-model="value" ng-options="question.id as question.text for question in set.questions" ng-change="remove($index+1, value);"></select>
    <br><br>
    </div>
```

Using ng-change you could pass in the array index of the set of questions. Then you could remove the selected question from all of the other question sets.

```
$scope.remove = function(key, val) {
      _.each($scope.questionSets, function(s) {

          if(s.id !== key) { 
              s.questions = _.reject(s.questions, function(q) {
                return q.id=== val;
              });

          }
      })
  }
```

This doesn't handle the case where a user changes the selection multiple times on the first drop down (and multiple options are thus removed from all others), but you can add on to this general idea.

http://plnkr.co/edit/XOTGEc8PfvbUTYIZcL7G?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot i figured out that, since I am using jquery as well something does not play together very well...
It is working when I deactivate jQuery

Comment: Do you know why jquery Mobile interferes with the functionality of ng-repeat? Or more precisely why it interferes with the ng-model since the value is not displayed correctly...